# Java incompatibilidade de tipos

Tags: java, jdbc

```
String query = "INSERT INTO codigos(Nome,Codigo) VALUES( '"+nome+"','" +codigo+ "')";

 rs = st.executeUpdate(query);
```

`rs` é um `resulset`,
`st` é um `statement`, aparece um erro a dizer que há um incompatibilidade de tipos
necessita do tipo `java.sql.Resulset` e diz que encontra um `int`.
Não entendo o porque

Comment: Segundo a [documentação da api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html), o método `executeUpdate()` retorna um `int`

Comment: Leia [**isso**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injeção_de_SQL).

Comment: Como o @VictorStafusa recomendou se existem parametros na query prefira o PreparedStatement (inclusive ele faz o escape de caracteres especiais pra você, coisa que a concatenação não faz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você faz um insert, o retorno não é um ResultSet, e sim um inteiro contendo a quantidade de linhas afetadas pela transação executada.

Para recuperar algo via ResultSet utilizando executeUpdate seria para pegar o ID auto-incremento, dora isso não tem porque. Para testar faça assim:

```
st = Conn.prepareStatement(queryString, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
// [...] Parametros [...]
int K = st.executeUpdate();

if(K > 0) {
   rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();

   if (rs.next()) {
      SeuObjeto.setID(rs.getInt(1));
   }
}
```

Comment: Para usar o getGeneratedKeys() vc tem que avisar na construção do seu insert usando Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS

Comment: Sim acabei esquecendo de citar. Mas é fato. Obrigado pelo alerta. Resposta ajustada!